# Modification on this wikipedia example for strategy pattern

Tags: design-patterns, software-design

[Considering **this** java example for strategy pattern:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

If we have a new customer type e.g. MemberCustomer who can also be charged with loyalty points he has. The billing strategy may change for normal or happy hours as follows:

```
NormalStrategyForMemberCustomer{
    double getActPrice(double rawPrice, int loyaltyPoints){
        return Math.max(rawPrice - loyaltyPoints, 0);
    }
}

HappyHoursStrategyForMemberCustomer{
    double getActPrice(double rawPrice, int loyaltyPoints){
        return Math.max(rawPrice*0.5 - loyaltyPoints, 0);
    }
}
```

In this case should I create the above methods as new strategies and inherit a new class from Customer class as MemberCustomer and try to fit the strategy pattern?

Or is there another design pattern which fits better here?

Also, I know moving down the logic of subtracting the rawPrice with loyalty points can be moved down to the final create bill step, but I am doing it to make it analogous to the problem I have in my workplace.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use types. Please correct me if I have mis-understood the problem.

```
private class Customer
{
    Strategy<StrategyParam> s;
}

private class MemberCustomer
{
    Strategy<LoyaltyStrategyParam> s;
}

private interface Strategy<T extends StrategyParam>
{
  double getActAmount(T param);
}

private class StrategyParam {
    double rawPrice;
}

private class LoyaltyStrategyParam extends StrategyParam {
    int loyaltyPoints;
}

private class MemberStrategy implements Strategy<StrategyParam>
{
    double getActAmount(StrategyParam param);
}

private class HappyHourMemberStrategy implements Strategy<LoyaltyStrategyParam>
{
    double getActAmount(LoyaltyStrategyParam param);
}
```